# expanding a text view when user clicks on "more..."

Tags: xcode, uitextview

There are applications with a text field that shows a given amount of lines and when the user clicks more it expands and shows the rest,
I'm familiar with the code to expand my UITextView but not sure how to add the "more..." and then "less...",

option to [image: it]

**Fine tuning the question:** I'm not looking to add a button but having the default IOS behavior when the text is larger than the size of a control it will either place ... at the end or in the middle for example: this is ... or thi...long

Answer (score 0):

you can take one button and add that UIButton to view below the UITextView and when you click on that button change the button positions and title related to the UITextView.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement that using the Method (sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:)

Firstly take out the size of the text you need show into the TextField like this

```
 NSString *textToBeShown = @"jhfsdg djsgf jdsfsdf dsf";
 CGSize  textSize =  [textToBeShown sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:11]] 
                                constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(constrainedWidth,constrainedHeight)
                                    lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
```

Suppose you want your textview height to be 100.0 initially before pressing "ShowMore" button then you can check the textSize.height in comparison to the 100.0 , if the textHeight is less then 100.0 then assign the TextView's Heigth as textSize.height else assign it 100.0 pixel .
Now when the show more button is clicked assign the textSize.height as the height of the UITextView used to show the text .

```
NSString *textToBeShown = @"jhfsdg djsgf jdsfsdf dsf";
CGSize  textSize =  [textToBeShown sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:11]] 
                            constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(constrainedWidth,constrainedHeight)
                                lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

textView.frame=CGRectMale(textView.frame.origin.x,
                          textView.frame.origin.y,
                          textSize.width,
                          textSize.height);
```